# How to configure the number of retries HtmlUnit request in Spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot, htmlunit

I use HtmlUnit and Spring. I have a webservice which is accepting a POST method with XML. It is working fine then at some random occasion, it fails to communicate to the server throwing IOException with message **The target server failed to respond.**

```
19:32:01.489 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 5][route: {}->http://][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 6; total allocated: 0 of 20]
19:32:01.489 [main] INFO org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec - I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {}->http:// The target server failed to respond
19:32:01.489 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec - The target server failed to respond
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond


    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_52);
    webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(20000);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(20000);
```

I see that some random requests is accept, but some reject. This situations was then I use Spring Boot! Because container doesn't handle response many (3) times. If I run test without spring, request executed per 3 attempts.
is it possible to configure the number of retries and if how?
Or how to avoid this problem and execute request at once?

Answer (score 1):

Probably, it is a bug in the HttpClient.

If you are using the HttpClient 4.4, please try to upgrade to 4.4.1.

If you want for more information, please look at [this link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1610).

If you can't upgrade, the following links might be helpful.

http://www.nuxeo.com/blog/using-httpclient-properly-avoid-closewait-tcp-connections/

Comment: Thank you for answer.  I don't understand how I can try to upgrade HttpClient 4.4 to 4.4.1 if use HtmlUnit???